# Vue - You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs

I'using Vue and babel.

I have an exported function

```
  //file a.js
  export async function get() { ... }
```

i need to connect this exported function to a static method of MyClass

```
// file b.js
import myInterface from './a.js'

export class MyClass {

    constructor() { ... }

    static myFunction = myInterface.get // <=== error line 36 
}
```

but i receive the following error:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (36:8) File was processed with 
>   these loaders:  * 
>   ./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js
>   You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these 
>   loaders.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Have you happened to use `vuetify`? If so make sure `vue-cli-plugin-vuetify` and `vuetify-loader` are sync. Either use `vue add vuetify` or `npm install` the latest version of them.

Comment: Can you explain more or link to a resource? Have the same issue, also Vuetify